# How to select first and last records between certain date parameters?

Tags: t-sql

I need a Query to extract the first instance and last instance only between date parameters.
I have a Table recording financial information with financialyearenddate field linked to `Company` table via `companyID`.  Each company is also linked to `programme` table and can have multiple programmes.  I have a report to pull the financials for each company 
on certain programme which I have adjusted to pull only the first and last instance (using MIN & MAX) however I need the first instance.
after a certain date parameter and the last instance before a certain date parameter.

**Example**:  Company ABloggs has financials for 1999,2000,2001,2004,2006,2007,2009 but the programme ran from 2001 to 2007 so I only want 
the first financial record and last financial record between those years i.e. 2001 & 2007 records.  Any help appreciated.
At the moment I am using 2 queries as I needed the data in a hurry but I need it in 1 query and only where financial year end dates are between parameters and only where there are minimum of 2 GVA records for a company.

***Query1***:

```
SELECT 
    gva.ccx_companyname, 
    gva.ccx_depreciation, 
    gva.ccx_exportturnover, 
    gva.ccx_financialyearenddate, 
    gva.ccx_netprofitbeforetax, 
    gva.ccx_totalturnover, 
    gva.ccx_totalwages, 
    gva.ccx_statusname, 
    gva.ccx_status, 
    gva.ccx_company, 
    gva.ccx_totalwages + gva.ccx_netprofitbeforetax + gva.ccx_depreciation AS GVA, 
    gva.ccx_nofulltimeequivalentemployees
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            ccx_companyname, 
            MAX(ccx_financialyearenddate) AS LatestDate
        FROM Filteredccx_gva AS Filteredccx_gva_1
        GROUP BY ccx_companyname
    ) AS min_1 
INNER JOIN Filteredccx_gva AS gva 
    ON min_1.ccx_companyname = gva.ccx_companyname AND 
       min_1.LatestDate = gva.ccx_financialyearenddate
WHERE (gva.ccx_status = ACTUAL)
```

***Query2:***

```
SELECT 
    gva.ccx_companyname, 
    gva.ccx_depreciation, 
    gva.ccx_exportturnover,
    gva.ccx_financialyearenddate, 
    gva.ccx_netprofitbeforetax, 
    gva.ccx_totalturnover,
    gva.ccx_totalwages, 
    gva.ccx_statusname, 
    gva.ccx_status, 
    gva.ccx_company, 
    gva.ccx_totalwages + gva.ccx_netprofitbeforetax + gva.ccx_depreciation AS GVA, 
    gva.ccx_nofulltimeequivalentemployees
FROM 
    (
         SELECT
             ccx_companyname, 
             MIN(ccx_financialyearenddate) AS FirstDate
         FROM Filteredccx_gva AS Filteredccx_gva_1
         GROUP BY ccx_companyname
    ) AS MAX_1 
INNER JOIN Filteredccx_gva AS gva 
    ON MAX_1.ccx_companyname = gva.ccx_companyname AND 
       MAX_1.FirstDate = gva.ccx_financialyearenddate
WHERE (gva.ccx_status = ACTUAL)
```

Comment: Sounds trivial. Post your query and tables definition.

Comment: Probably is trivial to you but it is extreamly important to the Management Information production.  Not sure what you mean by post query and tables definition - sorry - should I copy the query and post into a comment here?

Comment: You can edit your question and paste the query that you've tried, and how the tables are defined `create table Company(`...

Comment: Thank you Aryadev - have now posted query

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a where clause using the first and last date parameters. Something like this:

```
SELECT <companyId>, MIN(<date>), MAX(<date>)
FROM <table>
WHERE <date> BETWEEN @firstDate AND @lastDate
GROUP BY <companyId>
```

Comment: Thank you Young Bob for the reply but this gives me the financial year end dates in 2 columns and I want all the fields for the first and last records where the financial year end date falls between 2 dates. So I should end up with 2 rows per company (first and last record). I also only need results where the company has at least 2 records within the date parameters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @programme table (ccx_companyname varchar(max), start_year int, end_year int);
insert @programme values
('ABloggs', 2001, 2007);

declare @companies table (ccx_companyname varchar(max), ccx_financialyearenddate int);
insert @companies values
 ('ABloggs', 1999)
,('ABloggs', 2000)
,('ABloggs', 2001)
,('ABloggs', 2004)
,('ABloggs', 2006)
,('ABloggs', 2007)
,('ABloggs', 2009);

select c.ccx_companyname, min(ccx_financialyearenddate), max(ccx_financialyearenddate)
from @companies c
join @programme p on c.ccx_companyname = p.ccx_companyname
where c.ccx_financialyearenddate >= p.start_year and c.ccx_financialyearenddate <= p.end_year
group by c.ccx_companyname
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank You Aryadev.  Will have a go shortly. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your two original queries into a single query by including the MIN and MAX aggregates in the same GROUP BY query of the virtual table. Also including COUNT(*) and HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ensures company must have at least 2 dates. So query should look like:

```
SELECT 
    gva.ccx_companyname, 
    gva.ccx_depreciation, 
    gva.ccx_exportturnover,
    gva.ccx_financialyearenddate, 
    gva.ccx_netprofitbeforetax, 
    gva.ccx_totalturnover,
    gva.ccx_totalwages, 
    gva.ccx_statusname, 
    gva.ccx_status, 
    gva.ccx_company, 
    gva.ccx_totalwages + gva.ccx_netprofitbeforetax + gva.ccx_depreciation AS GVA, 
    gva.ccx_nofulltimeequivalentemployees
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ccx_companyname,
         ccx_status,
         MIN(ccx_financialyearenddate) AS FirstDate,
         MAX(ccx_financialyearenddate) AS LastDate,
         COUNT(*) AS NumDates
     FROM Filteredccx_gva AS Filteredccx_gva_1
     WHERE (ccx_status = ACTUAL)
     GROUP BY ccx_companyname, ccx_status
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS MinMax
INNER JOIN Filteredccx_gva AS gva 
      ON MinMax.ccx_companyname = gva.ccx_companyname AND 
         (MinMax.FirstDate = gva.ccx_financialyearenddate OR
          MinMax.LastDate = gva.ccx_financialyearenddate)
WHERE (gva.ccx_status = MinMax.ccx_status)
ORDER BY gva.ccx_companyname, gva.ccx_financialyearenddate
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I would never have got to that on my own.  This works except that it is pulling companies that have 2 gva records but I only need companies that have 2 gva records with status of Actual.  I  really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to move the WHERE condition into the inner GROUP BY query, which hopefully gives you what you want.

Comment: Thank You Young Bob for your precious time, unfortunately every time I execute the query the last WHERE clause is automatically removed and added into the line above so it ends up with:

Comment: Thank you @Young Bob - have replied in an answer rather than a comment as there were not enough characters permitted.